# Definition of symmetric probability mass function

Tags: probability, distributions, symmetry

Consider the random variables $Y$ characterised by a probability mass function (PMF) as follows:
$$
Y=\begin{cases}
-2 & \text{ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$}\\
2 & \text{ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$}\\
10 & \text{ with probability $0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Is this PMF considered **symmetric around zero**? I'm confused because  if I picture it it looks symmetric around zero (the last mass point does not appear as it has probability mass zero). However, from reading the [definition of symmetric probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution), it does not seem so.

Comment: A result with probability zero is not in the sample space and can thus be discarded no?

Comment: @Philip, that's a quite bold argument. Think about continuous distributions.

Comment: Sorry my mistake read this like a slot machine with 3 payouts. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is symmetric. One could also add $Y=5$ with probability $0$ to the definition as an option, too. Both formal and informal definitions in your link support this. The formal definition is finding a $x_0$ such that $$f(x_0+\delta)=f(x_0-\delta) \ \ \forall \delta$$ This $x_0$ here is $0.$

Comment: Thanks, but what happens for $\delta=10$? How is it f(10)=f(-10) if $-10$ is not considered in my definition of $Y$? Are we implicitly augmenting the support of $Y$ including $-10$? I think there is some underlying argument on the definition of support that I'm missing. I want to focus on discrete random variables.

Comment: Normally, your definition should have $-2$ and $2$, and an else statement, stating that we have zero probability when our variable is none of the above. For discrete RVs, PMF is actually a probability: $f_X(x)=P(X=x)$. So, whether you define it or not, $P(Y=-10)$ is $0$.